# NativeBase setup/installation error

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, visual-studio-code, native-base

I am trying to setup/install Native-Base in my React-Native project using the [official document](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html). But getting error every time.

**Command:** `npm install native-base --save`

**Error:**

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...yish/-/is-arrayish-0.'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /home/abhijitsrivastava/.npm/_logs/2018-07-04T06_03_24_057Z-debug.log

**System Specification:**

```
node --version
v8.1.0

npm --version
6.0.0

react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.4

Machine: Ubuntu 16.04LTS

IDE: Visual Studio Code Version 1.23.0
```

As per the [compatibility](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/Compatibility.html) matrix every thing is looking OK. I don't know how can I fix it.

**Update :**

Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-navigation": "^2.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed in a recent forum post where they've recommeneded to use `yarn` in place of `npm` for installing the dependencies and for creating the react native app.

**Yarn:** https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable

After installing yarn try issuing the below command,

```
yarn add native-base --save
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a running react native project which is based of npm. I am just trying to add native-base lib for the UI part. wanted to fix it is possible.

Comment: Can you please update your post with your `package.json`?

Comment: Can you try executing `npm cache clean --force` and then followed by the `npm install` and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Tried on same lines, no issues

[image]

```
    {
    "name": "NativebaseKitchenSink",
    "version": "2.5.2",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
        "eslint": "4.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.0.1",
        "flow-bin": "0.52.0",
        "flow-typed": "2.1.5",
        "husky": "0.14.3",
        "jest": "20.0.4",
        "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
        "prettier": "1.5.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native start",
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "color": "1.0.3",
        "lodash": "4.13.1",
        "moment": "2.13.0",
        "native-base": "^2.6.1",
        "react": "16.3.1",
        "react-native": "0.55.4",
        "react-navigation": "1.5.0"
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue you can try to change your node js version

npm install native-base this is giving issue with 18.7.0 version but

change to

**version 16.16.0 LTS for this it is working properly**
https://nodejs.org/en/